# Hyperledger-Fabric Error adding an organization to an existing channel

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I am getting an error when following the tutorial for adding an new organization in the channel .
The command I typed is

```
./eyfn.sh up
```

The output below is the error I got.

```
    + res=1
+ set +x
+ peer channel join -b mychannel.block
CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org3.example.com/peers/peer0.org3.example.com/tls/ca.crt
CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org3.example.com/peers/peer0.org3.example.com/tls/server.key
CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org3MSP
CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org3.example.com/peers/peer0.org3.example.com/tls/server.crt
CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org3.example.com/users/Admin@org3.example.com/msp
CORE_PEER_ID=Org3cli
CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=INFO
CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org3.example.com:7051
2018-06-19 22:08:40.019 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 001 Endorser and orderer connections initialized
Error: proposal failed (err: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = chaincode error (status: 500, message: Cannot create ledger from genesis block, due to LedgerID already exists))
Usage:
  peer channel join [flags]

Flags:
  -b, --blockpath string   Path to file containing genesis block

Global Flags:
      --cafile string                       Path to file containing PEM-encoded trusted certificate(s) for the ordering endpoint
      --certfile string                     Path to file containing PEM-encoded X509 public key to use for mutual TLS communication with the orderer endpoint
      --clientauth                          Use mutual TLS when communicating with the orderer endpoint
      --keyfile string                      Path to file containing PEM-encoded private key to use for mutual TLS communication with the orderer endpoint
      --logging-level string                Default logging level and overrides, see core.yaml for full syntax
  -o, --orderer string                      Ordering service endpoint
      --ordererTLSHostnameOverride string   The hostname override to use when validating the TLS connection to the orderer.
      --tls                                 Use TLS when communicating with the orderer endpoint
  -v, --version                             Display current version of fabric peer server

peer0.org3 failed to join the channel, Retry after 3 seconds
```

Specifically the error in the outputs seems to be this,

```
Error: proposal failed (err: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = chaincode error (status: 500, message: Cannot create ledger from genesis block, due to LedgerID already exists))
```

I am following instructions from the http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/channel_update_tutorial.html.

Any guidance seem to be helpful.

Comment: See this response here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47887886/fabric-sample-cannot-create-ledger-from-genesis-block-due-to-ledgerid-already

Answer (score 0):

Run this command

```
./byfn.sh -m down
```

And then run

```
./eyfn.sh up
```

Hope this help!